# In C, how can I check if the content of a string is not a number (where negative numbers are allowed)?

Tags: c, string, numerical

Suppose my string is "g9". I want my check to indicate that the string doesn't contain a number. However
if my string is "123" or "-123", it should indicate that it's a number and it should return that string.

Comment: "g9" **does** contain a number 9

Comment: I think he means none are digits.  Use std::none_of and std::isdigit.

Comment: `char *endptr; strtol(test_string, 10, &endptr); if (test_string == endptr || *endptr) Bad_Input();`

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you want as the verdict if the string is `0xA` or `9e1`? They're hexadecimal and floating point numbers. What about 98765432109876543210?  It's a valid decimal integer, but larger than fits in a 64-bit integer. You might want to investigate `strtol()` and `strtod()`, seeing whether they they use everything in the string when successfully converting it to a number.

Comment: @chux Sequence of argument of strtol is different.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Yes just saw that 2 minutes ago too.  Should be `strtol(test_string, &endptr, 10);`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried isdigit but it doesn't work with negative numbers. I also tried using strtok() to remove the negative sign before parsing but this gave me a seg error. It's possible that my implementation was ok and that it was another section of code that caused an error but this requires some testing, which is what I'm currently doing now.

Comment: @prestokeys I think there is neither `std::none_of` nor `std::isdigit` in C...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done at least in two ways:

1. Using [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) function which parses string until first invalid character is encountered and returns integer number evaluated so far. Unfortunately, it provides almost no means for diagnostics.
2. Better option is [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) which basically does the same thing, but returns pointer to first invalid character and sets `errno` if any error is encountered. Typical usage:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ...
   const char* const numStr = "123";
   char* end;
   const long i = strtol(numStr, &end, 10);
   ```

   The `end` parameter allows you to check if the whole string was recognised as a valid number (in this case corresponding character is `'\0'`):

   ```
   const int ok = (*end == '\0' && end != numStr);
   ```

Follow provided links for examples and more info. Also, you may consider related functions in *See also* section.

Comment: Notice the tags: this question is about C, you've posted C++.

Comment: It appears you are mixing c++ namespace syntax with c. There is no need for `std::` or `bool`. Otherwise your answer is correct. (better - now fix `long i = ...` and the text in `1` `2`) and it will be fine.

Comment: @David you're right. Updated my answer.

Comment: `strtol(numStr, &end, 10); ok = (*end == '\0')` fails to detect a problem with `""`.